# Travis CI + ruby on Rails package installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I tried to add Travis VI with my public [github](https://github.com/ferdinandrosario/mp3-meta-info) repository. 
to use taglib-ruby user should install **libtag1-dev** package on there system. so i wrote my .travis.yml file like the below

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.0.0

env:
  - DB=mysql
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get install -y libtag1-dev
script:
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
  - bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
  - bundle exec rspec spec/
before_script:
  - mysql -e 'create database my_app_test'
```

but travis always failed by telling the following

```
Installing rack-cache 1.2
Installing rack-test 0.6.2
Installing rack-ssl 1.3.4

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lstdc++... yes
checking for main() in -ltag... no
You must have taglib installed in order to use taglib-ruby.
Debian/Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install libtag1-dev
Fedora/RHEL: sudo yum install taglib-devel
Brew: brew install taglib
MacPorts: sudo port install taglib
```

Comment: If you check the logs of **before_install** does it install libtag1-dev properly? Is there any warnings/errors?

Comment: @ViktorBenei thanks for the response. I resolved the issue and posted the travis-CI file below.

Answer (score 5):

I resolved using the below

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.0.0

env:
  - DB=postgresql
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get install -y libtag1-dev
before_script:
  - psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres
  - "bundle exec rake db:migrate"
```